# mkdir on Python and Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Python2, Mac OS X 10.11...

I found it on github. Everything is working fine expect this:

```
error = Popen("%s \"mkdir -p '%s'\"" % (PathZero, MyPath), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).stderr.read()
    if error != '':
        send_msg("%sError creating path:\n\t%s" % (red_minus, error), False)
    else:
        send_msg("%sCreated path '%s'.\n" % (PathTwo, PathOne), False)
```

I'm always get:

> Error creating path
>
> /bin/sh: /Users/test/Downloads/File: Permission denied

I don't need "sudo" for this folder. And I think there some problems with this one : Popen("%s \"mkdir -p '%s'\""

Comment: What is `PathZero` supposed to be? Most of this is irrelevant, though, because you should just be using `os.makedirs` instead of shelling out to run `mkdir`.

Comment: @chepner PathZero - is that path /Users/test/Downloads/File

Comment: Well, there's your problem: whatever `File` is, you are attempting to run it as a command. The first thing I would try now is `Popen([PathZero, "mkdir -p '%s'".format(MyPath))`, without `shell=True`. Note, though, that this assumes that `File` really *is* executable.

Comment: There's really not enough context available to provide a decent answer, though.